# How does a helm value file gets tested

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

All the public helm charts  value file has configurable section commented eg ingress, OAuth etc on their master branch.

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths: []
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
```

How are there values getting validated before they are merged to master or before its is shipped?
Is there is a automated way of populating  helm value file with data that needs to tested with ?